# Draw line from origin to a user clicked coordinate in XYPlot of JFree chart

Tags: jfreechart

I have a XYPlot in JFree Chart with origin at (0,0).Now user clicks on anywhere in the chart.On clicking I want to draw a line from the origin to the coordinate point and extend the line till the end of the chart.

Please suggest!

I am new to Jfreechart and required this solution urgently.

Thanks in advance!

Sanjoy

Comment: One simple way is to use a ChartMouseListener. Refer to the answer [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523128/jfree-chart-find-subplot

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to override [`mousePressed()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#mousePressed%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) to get the coordinates and override [`drawSecondaryPass()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html#drawSecondaryPass%28java.awt.Graphics2D,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot,%20org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.CrosshairState,%20org.jfree.chart.entity.EntityCollection%29) to draw the line.