# Jfree chart Find Subplot

Tags: jfreechart

This may sound very basic as a question, but i am stuck in JFreechart use.

Let me lay out my problem :

1. I have a CombinedDomainXYPlot to which I add my subplots as and when required.
2. I have used my custom JPopup menu and have included a menu item that is intended to provide user the facility to delete a particular subplot
3. I am assuming that one can find a subplot using findSubplot method of the main plot. I am  able to get mouse positions but not able to do anything with PlotRenderingInfo that's required as input.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: I would like to locate a subplot of a combineddomainxyplot. I assume that it can be done using findSubplot(PlotRenderingInfo info,Point2D source) method. I am able to locate the 2DPoint so that's not the problem. How do I get the PlotRendering info parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a `List` of subplots using [`getSubplots()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainXYPlot.html#getSubplots%28%29). To learn which subplot was clicked, examine the [`ChartMouseEvent`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseEvent.html) that was sent from the `ChartPanel`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219445/230513).

Addendum: Here's a simple implementation of `ChartMouseListener` that will show each `ChartEntity` as it is clicked.

```
ChartPanel panel = ...
panel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getEntity().getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent event) {}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @trashgod . I am able to get the chart entity now and I already have the List of subplots. I am confused how to remove the subplot because code above gives me Chart Entity. I tried using the `getClass` as described above. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh Got it solved.  `PlotEntity entity = (PlotEntity) event.getEntity();
                XYPlot subplot = (XYPlot) entity.getPlot();
                plot.remove(subplot);` Where `plot` represents my CombinedDomainXYPlot. Thanks a million @trashgod

Comment: There is another simple way to do this that can be called from anywhere ... `plot.findSubplot(chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo(), chartPanel.getMousePosition());` Where  "chartPanel" is your `ChartPanel` object