# Displaying labels vertically on bars in barCharts in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I was unable to find a way to display the labels (the corresponding values of y axis) vertically. By default it displays horizontally but if values are big it gets overlapped.
Please I am not looking to vertically display the labels of domain axis (x axis) but to display corresponding y values as a label on top of bar horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

`BarChartDemo7` among the [demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) is an example.

Crowding can be a problem, but changing `ItemLabelPosition` or the `ItemLabelAnchor` may not solve the problem. As an alternative, consider using a tooltip generator, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770477/230513). For more complex rendering needs, add a `ChartMouseListener`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525187/230513), and update an adjacent component with the details.