# getChartRenderingInformation() getScreenDataArea() both with zero values

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to use following method to get screen coordinates.but I am not able.Because when I call this function, ChartPanel is not added its parent Java Form.So it does not know coordinates.
how can I force Chartpanel to draw yourself.

```
chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getSubplotInfo(0).getDataArea();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Why do you need `ChartPanel` coordinates? Why not use a `ChartMouseListener`.

Comment: I want to draw XYLineannotation to graph.I want these coordinates

Comment: to specify end location for line.To calculate end point I must know to pixel point of first time tick unit in graph, the I will add some pixel, then I must convert last pixel value to Time Value in graph.I will show this line when chart is displayed, it will not drawn after an mouse event occurs.So  I do not use ChartMouseListener.Do you think that I must addChartMouseListener to ChartPanel to get screen coordinate

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24933).

Comment: I understand problem.When I try to get screen data area , it returns null values, because ChartPanel is not be drawn yet, it is not added parent Swing Form.So coordinates are not calculated.I have to force ChartPanel to draw yourself

Answer (score 1):

Adding a [`ChartMouseListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html) to your `ChartPanel` is one way to get a [`ChartMouseEvent`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseEvent.html) and the corresponding `java.awt.event.MouseEvent`.

Addendum: You might look at the annotation examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802375/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620017/230513).

Addendum: Absent a *complete* [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the exception you describe, it's difficult to suggest how to debug unseen code; at a guess, I'd examine the problem subplot, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525187/230513).

Comment: But I do not want to have ChartMouseEvent.I just want to convert data space value to coordinate pixel value without any mouse event

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish; I've added links to related examples above.

Comment: Sorry, These links does not describe my problem.I updated the problem description.Please read